user defined array object and want to create a default constructor and parameterized constructor in Java
Hi I'm very new to Object Oriented Programming and just starting to learn Java.
I have a user defined array object and I want to initialize it using default constructor and parameterized constructor but I don't know how to do it. I was wondering if I could get some help.
public class Example
{
    // fields 
    private String foo;
    private Obj obj; 
    private Obj2[] objarr;

    // default constructor
    public Example()
    {
        foo = "";
        obj = new Obj();
        // i don't know what to do with Obj[] objarr for this.. 
    }

    // parameterized constructor
    public Example(String foo, Obj obj, Obj2[] objarr)
    {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.obj = obj;
        this.objarr = objarr; // i don't know if this is correct 
    }
}

Thank you so much for you time.
So far for default constructor i've tried the following but i don't know if this is correct
    // default constructor
    public Example()
    {
        foo = "";
        obj1 = new Obj();
        obj = new Obj2[3];
    }

as for parameterized constructor i've put Obj2[] objarr as parameter and inside the body i wrote
this.objarr = objarr; but it's getting an error.

It depends on how much you want your array to hold

If you are learning a new language it is always worth making use of the official tutorials. Take a look  at the Java Tutorilas section on Arrays.

Always study The Java Tutorials before posting here. Oracle provides them free of cost. Another great resource for beginners is the book, Head First Java, 3rd Edition.

When posting about an error, post the error!

What you want is initializing your variable Obj2[] objarr;. It seems that you created a custom object named Obj2. To initialize, you will do:
Obj2[] objarr = new Obj2[2];  //where 2 is the dimension of your array

What you have written for the default constructor is correct except for obj1 that comes from nowhere. Also take a look at this link.
